# What's the special key to defeat the Developper?

Tags: candy-box

In the Developper's Computer, I must press a certain key to kill the developper. What is it?

Comment: Simply roll your face across the keyboard to win!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The code that chooses which letter to press is:

`this.letter = 65 + random.getRandomIntUpTo(25);`

So it could be any letter between *a* and *z* -- mash those keys quickly!  (This is easier with a chiclet keyboard where you can just brush your hand across them.)  Maybe an invincibility potion can buy you some time?

Comment: Turtle/Invuln and unicorn horn help for certain

Answer (score 5):

The key which you have to press seems to be chosen at random. So far I've gotten *A*, *Q* and *G*.

Comment: I've checked the source, it is random, and different every time.

Comment: How does this work? Do I only get one guess?

Comment: @galacticninja No. You can keep guessing so long as you're alive.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the key to press by putting this code into the console *while in the quest*:

`String.fromCharCode(developperComputer.letter)`